# Error 207 occurs without a reason (invalid floating point operation.)

Tags: floating-point, runtime-error, pascal

When I run my program, an error occurs:

```
program lab_1_27;
uses crt;
var
x, y, z: real;
a: integer;


function pow_udf(m, n:real) : real;
var
  result: real;
begin
  result:= exp(y * ln(x));
end;


begin
  clrscr;

  readln(x);
  readln(y);
  z:= pow_udf(x, y);

  a:= round(z); (* a cursor is in this line after terminating the program *)
  writeln(a);

readkey;
end.
```

Error:

```
Error 207: invalid floating point operation.
```

Please, tell me what is the reason of such behavior because I can't fund it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function pow_udf(m, n:real) : real;
var
  result: real;
begin
  result:= exp(y * ln(x));
end;
```

The above code assigns the calculation to a local variable named `result` but fails to return any result from the function. Also it's working on global variables `x` and `y`, not on the variables that's passed to the function. Replace it with:

```
function pow_udf(m, n:real) : real;
begin
  pow_udf:= exp(n * ln(m));
end;
```

Comment: `pow_udf` is some kind of "variable", am I right? Because it was declared exactly as other variables do... `pow_udf ... : real;`

Comment: Not as far as the language is concerned. Technically, probably. What you've declared with that name is a 'function', not a 'variable'. The name of the function is the inherent 'result'. The compiler you're using is very old. As far as I know, all modern pascal compilers have built-in 'result' for returning a value from a function, you don't declare it - it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I was having this same error in a program and my solution was different; might help others searching this error code.

For my program I had used compiler directive N-, and by switching it to N+ I saw a considerable speed increase, but then error 207 started popping up.

Either add directive N- at the top of your source, eg.

```
{$N-}
PROGRAM ExampleProg;
USES Crt, Dos;
```

or go into compiler options and disable 8087/80287 processing.  This may solve your issue.

Note: if you have compiler directive N+ defined in your source, then changing the options in the IDE won't do a thing; the source code overrules!

Comment: Indeed, seems useful)